# Parsing JSON output using Mechanize and Python Django View

Tags: python, django, json, parsing, mechanize

I'm currently doing a site search like : `site:somedomain.com` into BING using Python and Mechanize.

It is submitting fine to bing and returning an output - looks like Json? I can't seem to figure out a good way to further parse the results. **Is it JSON?**

I'm getting an output like:

```
Link(base_url=u'http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Asomesite.com', url='http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=478', text='SomeSite -  Professor Rating of Louis Scerbo', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=478'), ('h', 'ID=SERP,5105.1')])Link(base_url=u'http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Asomesite.com', url='http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=527', text='SomeSite -  Professor Rating of Jahan \xe2\x80\xa6', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=527'), ('h', 'ID=SERP,5118.1')])Link(base_url=u'http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Asomesite.com', url='http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=645', text='SomeSite -  Professor Rating of David Kutzik', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=645'), ('h', 'ID=SERP,5131.1')])
```

I want to get all the urls like:

```
http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=478
http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=527
http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=645
```

and so on, so the `url` attribute within

How can I further do this with mechanize within my code? Keep in mind, some urls in the future might look like:

```
http://www.anothersite.com/dir/dir/dir/send.php?pID=100
```

Thank you !

Comment: If you're using Microsoft's Azure API to get Bing results, you may append "format=JSON" as GET param to your request URL. Then you'll receive a JSON string as response object.

Comment: Can you show a brief example of just the url? Does it matter when format=JSON is appended?

Comment: Do you have any idea what kind of output that is in my above question? I cannot find it for the life of me

Comment: Using Python requests (no indenting possible as comment):                     req = requests.get(u'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?$format=JSON&&Query=%%27%s%%27' % urllib.quote(q.encode('utf8'), ''), auth=('', u'YOU_API_KEY'))
                    results = req.json()['d']['results']

Comment: That looks horrible as a comment ... I'll create a proper answer, even if it's not 100% accurate to the question ...

Comment: Please also address potentially what kind of output that is in my question. Would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Okay, done ... if you have questions, just shoot ... This approach is working nicely in our projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well mechanize is more a browser like package for Python, for parsing HTML/XML I would recommend Lxml, you can feed that data to lxml and look for urls. Another option is to use regular expressions to look for urls, this approach would be more flexible.

```
import re 
url_regex = re.compile('http:[^\']+')
urls = re.findall(url_regex, html_text)
```

Edit:

Well instead of printing `output`, just pass `output` instead of `html_text` in `re.findall()` and then print `urls`

Comment: @CodeTalk edited, its really simple, you gotta play with it, findall() receives a regular expression and a string to look into. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I will have to play around with this a bit I guess

Comment: One question - is that output I provided above html though?

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft's Azure Datamarket API with Python requests, you can request JSON strings directly:

```
import requests, urllib
q = u'Hello World'
q = urllib.quote(q.encode('utf8'), '')
req = requests.get(
    u'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?$format=JSON&Query=%%27%s%%27' % q,
    auth=('', u'YOU_API_KEY')
)
# print req.json()
results = req.json()['d']['results']
list_of_urls = [ r['Url'] for r in results]
```

Depending on your input data you may or may not need the .encode('utf8') part of "q". The "site:xy.com" query should work, too, but I didn't test this. Additionally, we occasionally had some strange encodings returned from Bing ... so we had to re-encode returned URLs like so:

```
url = r['Url'].encode('latin1')
```

But those were really special cases ...

You need to register for the Azure API (free of charge) and up to 5000 Bing search requests per month are free: http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search

There are several params to fine tune your results: http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search#schema

Comment: Admitted, I kind of sound like that :-) But no, we originally used Google's search API, but that has turned into "paid only". Bing is (to my knowledge) the only viable search engine that still provides a free API - even if limited in requests.

Comment: It isn't free anymore.

Comment: Read the links I've posted: it is free up to 5,000 requests per month and we're currently using it in our projects.

Comment: Does a request = 1 extract from one search result? e.g. the first page for a given query and each additional page is another request ?

Comment: The "requests.get" part in your Python script is the request. No matter which content you retrieve, calling the API counts as one request. E.g. if you get 100 search results in one JSON response, it counts as one request.